# How to do multiple submits on webpage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, automation, submit, sleep

There are a lot of submit buttons on my web page. I tried this :

```
javascript:var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
   if (x[i].type == 'submit') {
      x[i].click();
   }
};
```

It start to submit but do it very fast. or many time, my web page freezes. I thought to have a pause or sleep between each submit. I googled for and read lots of thread in stack-overflow too. JavaScript do not have pause or sleep. There are some alternatives like Timeout but many people suggested against using it. I understood that it is not a good idea to try to have a pause or sleep in-between.

So, I out of ideas now. How I will do those multiple submits, one by one? can anyone give me right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add return type to it or return false or return true that will help you from my point of view obviously its not good idea to do

Comment: Why do you want to click all submit buttons on a page at once? Usually this is not necessary.

Comment: Why do you need to do several submits? Can't you serialise all the inputs on the page and send them all at once?

Comment: @MikeW : I want to submit one by one.

Answer (score 0):

try with a small delay, 50 ms or so

```
 javascript:var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
    if (x[i].type == 'submit') {
       setTimeout(function() {
          x[i].click();
       }, 50);
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work unless you're very lucky. Each submit causes a page reload. If you submit again too quickly the first page load is aborted, which could mean any associated processing is either abandoned, or only partially complete. You need to wait for each submit to complete before sending the next, or send all the data in one block.

Adding an arbitrary delay of, say, 50ms might be enough sometimes, but on others it will be unnecessarily long, or not long enough.

Alternatively, you could send your data with AJAX, waiting for each response. This would be more reliable, but since each submit requires a round trip plus the processing time, the total time to submit could rise from, say, 100ms to 1.5 to 2 seconds.

Compare that with a single submit, where all the data could be sent in the first submit - 100ms.